# Data Structure/ Data Type - private int [ , ] mydata;

Tags: c#

a piece of C# code,  written as

private int[ , ] mydata;

I am curious what kind of data type for mydata? Is it a array? What is the comma in the bracket used for?

Thank you ahead for sharing your thought!

Comment: That would be a two-dimensional array Or more than that. You can also specify more dimensions: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2yd9wwz4.aspx

Comment: You can read the [documentation on arrays](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9b9dty7d.aspx) for more info as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're looking at is a Multidimensional Array:

Well explained at MSDN:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2yd9wwz4.aspx

Answer (score 0):

This is used to represent a 2D array

access , item at row 1 column 1 like so : `a[1,1]`

a visual representation of a 2,2 matrix is :

> 1 1
>   0 2

and `a[1,1]` returns 2